# DOCTRINE field size does not get limited

Tags: php, doctrine

still learning doctrine.

Shouldn't this limit the field size?
`* @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text", length=4)`

It does not, could enter a text size of more than four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit your text column's length, use the type "string" and not "text".

Source: http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#string